# Indexing a Music Lyrics Database

Tags: php, python, database, search, indexing

So I want to index the lyrics from a lyrics website and then perform operations on the lyrics (search for certain artists, terms, patterns etc) .

I figure the best scenario is if there is already some structured file format for me to use--> anyone know if anything like this exists?

The next best thing would be a site that is "amenable" to what I am trying to do--> any such site?

Any comments in general about how I can do this speedily? (This is supposed to be a fun project and not a heavy duty application)

Thanks!

Comment: I am also interested in doing something like this. Did you get anywhere with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading the lyric database from a site is bad idea, you can query it for each lyric you want instead.

Even if you download all the lyrics, don't store them on a flat-file(maybe xml?), instead of use a database like sqlite. Otherwise the operations like searching or listing would be painful.

But no idea about amenable sites.

Edit; I found [ChartLyrics API](http://www.chartlyrics.com/api.aspx); you can use their API easily.

Answer (score 2):

Generally,

1) Download that lyric and store it in separate table in your database

table: **lyrics** (example)

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+
| lyr_id  | lyr_artist  | lyr_title       | lyr_content                   |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+
| 1       | Metallica   | The Unforgiven  | New blood joins this earth... |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+
...
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+
```

2) Search **artist** in column `lyr_artist`, **song title** in column `lyr_title`, **text** (keywords) in `lyr_content`, etc.

Query examples

```
SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE lyr_artist='artist';
SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE lyr_title='song_title';
SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE lyr_content LIKE '%word1%' AND lyr_content LIKE '%word2%'
```

Well, generally, something like that.. or mix WHERE condition. You can use WHERE...LIKE to columns like song title and artist too, for example to find song "The Unforgiven" if user asks for keyword "Unforgiven", etc.

3) Use query result to display search results

---

Note: Storing data in files on server is not as good as storing it in database, in terms of speed.